# How to specify custom element dependencies in Polymer

Tags: dependencies, polymer, custom-element

Sorry for trivial question, but suppose I want to have a custom element, say, 'my-login-form', which would include 'iron-input'. How do I denote that my form is dependent upon 'iron-input'? Should I use something like

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
```

in the beginning of 'my-login-form.html' file?

Answer (score 1):

Yup! That's pretty much the standard way of doing things. If you look at iron-input's source code, they do the same thing:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-input/blob/master/iron-input.html

However, elements don't need to import their dependencies directly, as long as the dependancies are imported somewhere within the webpage that uses the element. If you're working on a larger project, another common way of managing dependancies is to create a dedicated file, as seen here in the Polymer Starter Kit:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/elements/elements.html

In this case, index.html just imports this file, and all the custom elements will still work, even though they haven't imported any of their dependencies.

In my experience this has some tradeoffs. It becomes a lot easier to add dependencies since you only need to add them once, but it also becomes harder to remove them, since you have to make sure the given import isn't being used in any of your elements.